# flutter setstate from another function?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a void function called `updateCardCode()` which takes `newCardCode` as argument,
in the same class, I have a second function called `showPopUp()` which is an async function and returns showDialog function returns AlertDialog, also in the same class I have a build widget.

here is `updateCardCode()` code:

```
void updateCardCode(String newCardCode) {
    setState(() {
      cardCode1 = newCardCode;
    });
  }
```

`showPopUp()` calls `updateCardCode()` if certain conditions are met but I want setState to have a result on the Build widget which returns Scaffold. is that possible?

Comment: also, if its possible i want that setState to have result on another page

Answer (score 0):

call the setState at the end of the `showPopUp()` function like

`showPopUp().then(()=>setState((){}));`

Comment: I've tried that but it shows an error
'The argument type "void Function()" can't be assigned to the parameter type "FutureOr<dynamic> Function(void)".'